# Rmarkdown/Quarto Presentation ioslides Math equations

Tags: r, format, ioslides

I am having trouble with math text in the newest version of R using ioslides.  Is there a package or something I can download so my math equations look better?

Example code:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: ioslides_presentation
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```


## Slide with Math

$$ \overline{x} = \sum_{i = 1}^\infty x_i$$
````

Output:
[image]

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "better".  Do you want the formula to be bigger?

Comment: The formatting gets a little off.  For example, the overline bar is overlapping the equal sign

Comment: I see. I tried your code, and it looks good on my end. Have you tried opening the file in different browsers? Are your quarto and RStudio version up-to-date?

Comment: Yes, Yes, Yes.  This started after updating, happens on the three machines I tried it on.

Comment: It might be a bug then. Consider reporting it on github ([quarto issues](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+math)).